# Где найти примеры реализации Torrent-клиента?

Tags: python, torrent, c++

Давно хочу написать свой торрент-клиент, главная причина: хочется лучше разобраться в системе торрентов, ну и нужно отображать рейтинг на различных трекерах. Со вторым я разобрался: оказалось не сложно, а вот найти примеры или исходники клиентов не получилось.
Может, кто пытался писать или даже писал, может, кто просто знает где найти.

Язык, в общем, не важен, на каком будет пример, на том и будем писать. Если же все-таки нужны предпочтения `C++, QT, Python`

Comment: А разве трудно найти в интернете исходники Deluge, KTorrent, Transmission?

Comment: @Snaka, Следует править вопрос, а не добавлять комментарий. Комментарии нужны лишь для уточнений.

Answer (score 2):

[Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) - Python

[Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) - C, C++, GTK+, Qt

[KTorrent](http://ktorrent.org/) - C, C++

Answer (score 0):

На `C++` не знаю как обстоят дела, а на `.NET` есть проект [MonoTorrent](http://www.monotorrent.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример: [qbittorrent](http://www.qbittorrent.org/download.php).

Answer (score 0):

Создать свой torrent клиент несложно.
Пример торрент-клиента, написанного на бейсике. [pbtorrent.ucoz.ru](http://pbtorrent.ucoz.ru/)